# glTexImage2D run out of memory with a 4G-memory nVidia video card

Tags: c++, opengl

A piece of code:

```
// Some codes intializing 'transWidth' and 'transHeight' are ommitted
static vector<GLfloat> pixels;

printf("Alloc: %dx%dx4=%d floats\n", transWidth, transHeight, transWidth * transHeight * 4);
pixels.resize(transWidth * transHeight*4);
// Some codes modifying 'pixels'
// omitted

_CheckErrorGL
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA32F, transWidth, transHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, pixels.data());
_CheckErrorGL
```

The macro `_CheckErrorGL` is used to output the error code and description when necessary:

```
#define _CheckErrorGL {\
    GLenum code;\
    if ((code = glGetError()) != GL_NO_ERROR)\
    {\
        printf("Error %d: %s\n", int(code), gluErrorString(code));\
        assert(false);\
    }\
}
```

This code will be executed several times. Here is the output:

```
Ready for OpenGL 2.0
Alloc: 732x737x4=2157936 floats
Alloc: 3168x3224x4=40854528 floats
Alloc: 732x737x4=2157936 floats
Alloc: 3168x3224x4=40854528 floats
Error 1285: 内存不足
Alloc: 6561x1x4=26244 floats
Alloc: 732x737x4=2157936 floats
Alloc: 3168x3224x4=40854528 floats
Error 1285: 内存不足
Alloc: 732x737x4=2157936 floats
Alloc: 3168x3224x4=40854528 floats
Error 1285: 内存不足
Alloc: 6561x1x4=26244 floats
```

('内存不足' means 'out of memory'. And in Release mode the `assert` is just (void)0.)

The amount of the floats are 172102344, or 656.5MiB assuming a float is 4Bytes. And my video card is NVIDIA GeForce GTX 660 Ti with 4042MB memory. What happened?

**Update:**

I tried the suggestions from Andon and Surgey.

Here are my parameters of texture:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 0);
```

Still the same output. But when I change `RGBA32F` to `RGBA16F` or `RGBA` in

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA32F, transWidth, transHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, pixels.data());
```

Then all the allocations are successful. And I try the code on another machine with NVIDIA GeForce GTX Titan(4095MB video memory), but all the results are the same.

**Note**: I use dxdiag.exe to display the total video memory.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have hit a GPU-specific texture size limit.

Try changing your internal format `GL_RGBA32F` to `GL_RGBA16F` and then to `GL_RGBA` and see if you are able to create those textures.

Answer (score 1):

> my video card is NVIDIA GeForce GTX 660 Ti with 4042MB memory.

That 4042 MiB number includes GART (*Graphics Address Remapping Table* -- system shared memory) - your video card's actual dedicated memory is something different. Furthermore, in modern systems video memory (whether GART or dedicated) is shared between processes... you are not necessarily guaranteed to have access to 4042 MiB worth of storage in your individual applications.

Because you are using an NV GPU, you may find the [`GL_NVX_gpu_memory_info`](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/NVX/gpu_memory_info.txt) extension useful.

---

Last, your texture's actual storage requirements are not what you think they are.

You have 1000 texture LODs by default when you create a GL texture object, this code generates an incomplete texture because you only allocate data for one of the 1000 LODs. You should set `GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL` to **0** since you are only allocating storage for a single LOD.

*Alternatively, you could use `glTexStorage2D (...)` to correctly create a texture with 1 LOD, but that is not available in OpenGL 2.0.*